# Can club stations register callsigns on the D-Star network?

Tags: legal, digital-modes, canada, d-star

Some of the members at my local radio club are interested in working with D-Star. Since the equipment is very expensive, it was proposed that the club purchase and operate one rig collectively. Is there any precedent for registering a club station's callsign on the D-Star network for use by its members? What would be the potential consequences for operating in this manner? I don't know whether D-Star would be treated different from other transmission modes, hence the question.

Note that we are not setting up a D-Star repeater, only a terminal.

For the purposes of regulatory laws, we are located in Canada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After consulting with a Canadian D-STAR gateway operator, I have learned that **yes, club stations can register callsigns on D-STAR.** Operating in this manner would be no different than operating a club station over the air with a non D-STAR radio or using a D-STAR device with a personal callsign.

The one caveat to this is that if the club in question wishes to run a D-STAR repeater, it needs to be registered under a unique callsign, and cannot be shared with the callsign assigned to the D-STAR terminal. This would require the club to register a second callsign for use with the repeater.

(Thanks to Eric Meth VE3EI for helping provide this information)